# Duplicate Rows dynamically jquery based on checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox, addition

I am trying to dynamically add rows based in the checkbox checked. The idea here is to duplicate the selected row. For instance, initially there is only one row. On checking the checkbox corresponding to this row, it creates a duplicate of it. If i change the dropdown values in the newly added row , and duplicate it, its not able to do it because of my hardcodedness. How can i bring about this dynamicity?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#DuplicateRow").click(function() {
                var checkboxValues = [];
                $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                    //alert('hi') 
                    var row = document.getElementById("row"); // find row to copy
                    var table = document.getElementById("tabletomodify"); // find table to append to
                    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
                    clone.id = "row"; // change id or other attributes/contents
                    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>


<table cellpadding="10" style="border:2px solid black;" id="tabletomodify">
    <tr bgcolor="#360584">
        <td style="border:1px solid black;" colspan="15"><font face="Arial" size="4" color="white"><b><i>Records</i></b></font>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="AddRow">Add Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="DuplicateRow">Duplicate Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="DeleteRow">Delete Row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#360584">
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Name </font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Date of Birth</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">City</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">State</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Country</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Phone Number</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Mail ID</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Select</font>

        </td>
        <tr id="row">
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like you're reusing same id; ensure id attributes are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this .. this works, you have manually copy all the changed/selected options from actual row to cloned row

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#DuplicateRow").click(function(){
var checkboxValues = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
var $chkbox=$(this);
var $actualrow = $chkbox.closest('tr');
var $clonedRow = $actualrow.clone();
$clonedRow.find("select").each(function(i){
this.selectedIndex = $actualrow.find("select")[i].selectedIndex;
})
$chkbox.closest('#tabletomodify').append( $clonedRow );
});
});
});
```